# How can i fetch live stream from url?

Tags: python, opencv, urllib

I am using RPi-cam-web-interface and from pi camera, rasperry pi continuously throws image to a link, I want to process that image using opencv on my computer.

Here is the [link](https://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface#Web_Server_choice) software I'm using suggested by sentdex.

Here's a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTZMOHE8v-Q) to sentdex's video.

Streaming URL to extract image from
[image: This] is what it looks like, the url from which image is to be extracted.

Comment: What have you got so far? Any code you're playing with or a specific place you're getting stuck?

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/nficano/pytube), this is an awesome youtube downloader, if you understand this repository, then you can just tweak and do your job

Comment: Thanks for your support, I solved it by cont. pinging on photo.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing your url in VideoCapture like below:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
cap.opne("Your_URL")
```

Comment: yes, I tried, doesn't work. But I did found a solution though i.e. cont. pinging on the link of picture

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your RPI link into VLC player, it should work for this widget. You can stream from a url using [`cv2.videoCapture()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html). Change `rtsp_stream_link` to your RPI url.

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2

class RTSPVideoWriterObject(object):
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        # Create a VideoCapture object
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)

        # Default resolutions of the frame are obtained (system dependent)
        self.frame_width = int(self.capture.get(3))
        self.frame_height = int(self.capture.get(4))

        # Set up codec and output video settings
        self.codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
        self.output_video = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', self.codec, 30, (self.frame_width, self.frame_height))

        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()

    def show_frame(self):
        # Display frames in main program
        if self.status:
            cv2.imshow('frame', self.frame)

        # Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            self.output_video.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)

    def save_frame(self):
        # Save obtained frame into video output file
        self.output_video.write(self.frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rtsp_stream_link = 'your stream link!'
    video_stream_widget = RTSPVideoWriterObject(rtsp_stream_link)
    while True:
        try:
            video_stream_widget.show_frame()
            #video_stream_widget.save_frame()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```